# Ansible: Is it possible to add a list of dictionaries to an array?

Tags: ansible

I have been tasked with creating a list of dictionaries, and I need to iterate over it, and add the elements to another list - effectively creating a "list of lists of dictionaries".

So far, I have produced the following code within the Ansible role:

**ROLE**

```
- name: "Iteration"
  set_fact:
    pool_members:
      - name: "{{ item | split('.') | first }}"
        host: "{{ lookup( 'community.general.dig' , item) }}" # This just resolves the FQDN of the iterated item and adds the IP address as a value
        port: "{{pool_member_port | int}}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ groups['needed_hosts'] }}"
    when: 
      - condition == False
```

The playbook just calls the role and doesn't modify the variable: when I just call the `pool_members` fact, then I only get the last item of the group.

I'd like to understand if it's possible to add these items to an array, so that the `pool_members` fact, contains all of the definitions for the hosts, like so:

```
[
    - "name": "host-1.test.local"
      "host": "192.168.1.1"
      "port": "12345"
    
    - "name": "host-2.test.local"
      "host": "192.168.1.2"
      "port": "12345"
    
    - "name": "host-3.test.local"
      "host": "192.168.1.3"
      "port": "12345"
]
```

So that, when I call it, I have all of the members within the variable.

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Comment: sorry i dont understant what you want, could you give a sample, your start content and your final content...it will be easier to help you

Comment: Hello Frenchy, thanks for your reply. The `groups['needed_hosts'] ` part just loops over the inventory definition for the `needed_hosts` group - which is an FQDN - and uses the item in order to create the values for the dictionaries. You can see the desired output in the question: at the moment the list only returns the last item (in this case, just `"host-3.test.local"`). Hope this helps you better.

Comment: ah ok..you want to create a list of your result...

Comment: Yes. At the moment I have managed to do this with other variables such as strings, but never with a list of dictionaries, and I cannot figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not so close to the result, just use temporary variables and create your dictionary.

This playbook creates a list of dictionaries:

```
- name: "Iteration"
  set_fact:
    pool_members: "{{ pool_members | d([]) + [{'name': name, 'host': host, 'port': port}] }}"
  vars:
    name: "{{ item | split('.') | first }}"
    host: "{{ lookup( 'community.general.dig' , item) }}" # This just resolves the FQDN of the iterated item and adds the IP address as a value
    port: "{{pool_member_port | int}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['needed_hosts'] }}"
  when: 
    - condition == False
```

The filter `d([])` (or `default([])`) means: if the variable doesn't exist, initialize it to `[]`